# Are datareaders still faster than datasets?

Tags: .net, performance

I've been coding with .NET since it came out of beta. That's a long time and I should reexamine some of my assumptions to see if things changed.

One of my biggest assumptions is that datareader is faster than a dataset - http://www.sitepoint.com/dataset-datareader/

Is this still the case? Did anything change? I heard rumors there is something less "chatty" than datareaders now but can't find any articles to back it up. The idea was that when i "readnext" I have to do a database round trip while the alternative grabs everything at once in a single trip.

Is there a faster alternative to datareader now or is the article above still correct?

For the record, when I have a datareader all I do is place row values into an object, place the object into a hashtable, read the next row, repeat, then close the connection. Any logic connecting objects can be done using the hashtables after the connections are closed (freeing up the pool as quickly as possible).

Comment: "roomers" should be spelled "rumors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying logic of filling a `DataSet` via a `DbDataAdapter` object has not changed.  It still uses a `DbDataReader` to fill up the DataSet.  So, by definition, using a DataReader for the operation you describe will still be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like the roomers were just that - roomers.

Comment: @JSWork:  There are definitely more methods for grabbing data now (entity framework stuff, Linq, etc.).  Most of these provide more layers of abstraction.  For reading data directly from a database server, the DataReader is fairly thin.  It is of course implementation dependent by vendor, but the basic logic is to execute an SQL statement and then read rows of data back with nothing much else going on.  And since they are forward-only, it allows vendors to utilize read-ahead caching.  I don't know of faster ways (in .NET) for reading data like that, but I'm also not saying they don't exist.

Answer (score 2):

DataReaders and DataSets have different sets of functionality.  It doesn't matter how fast a DataReader might be if it doesn't have the functionality you need from a DataSet.  You're comparing apples and oranges.

If you want an apple, then use an apple, if you want an orange use that.  Use the best tool for the job.

Comment: My primary concern is the speed. I'm using datareaders because I don't need the functionality of the dataset.

I was worried was that something may have changed in the last 8 years and something faster than datareaders may have made datareaders obsolete.

Comment: @JSWork - The point is, DataSets aren't slower than DataReaders, because DataReaders can't do what DataSets can do.  It's different functionlity.  If you need a DataReader, then use a DataReader because it's the appropriate class to use, not because it's faster than something that isn't a DataReader.  If DataReaders are what you need, keep using them.

Comment: When speed is my primary concern could you give me a situation where it would be inappropriate to use a datareader instead of a dataset? I've never been in a situation before that required me to use a dataset instead of a datareader. If I'm doing this incorrectly with my dogmatic approach I'd love to know.

Comment: Part of my confusion lies in the article stating that datasets use datareaders to populate themselves. If this is the case, how are datasets not slower?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DataSets are still horribly slow so and you should never use them for any system that has more than 1 user or is a web app.